# generate image with two class Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, pattern-recognition, image-generation

I know hoy to generate an image with specific pixels:

> > img= randn(128,128);
> >     imshow(img);

Also I know how to generate an image with matrix:

> > x1 = random('unif',0,1,2,4)

x1 =

```
0.0012    0.3403    0.1536    0.2083
0.2753    0.9554    0.1373    0.8412
```

But how can I generate imagen with specific pixels with two class clasififiers Matlab?

Comment: What do you mean with class classifiers?

Comment: Can you give an example of the image you're trying to generate? What will this image be used for?